# How can I patch Icons.config file?

Tags: configuration

I need to add some custom icons to **Icons.config**, but I would like to do it through a patch.

Is there any way to do so?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <collection name="Foo">
    Foo/16x16/logo.png
  </collection>
  <collection name="Foo2">
    Foo/16x16/logo.png
  </collection>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I found out a way to patch the Icons.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <icons>
      <collection name="Foo">
        Foo/16x16/logo.png
      </collection>
      <collection name="Foo2">
        Foo/16x16/logo.png
      </collection>
    </icons>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

In theory, everything you see in the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx is patchable.